# My shortcut from desktop for Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition cannot open

Tags: database, oracle11g

The error when i try to open the shortcut : Windows cannot find 'http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again

Alternative :
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:418772923647340
I know i can type this link in browser to access it. Works for me.

But i want to know how to fix the error from my desktop shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Well, your shortcut seems to start with `http:/.` instead of `http://` ...? You might need to replace `%HTTPPORT%` with `8080` too if it doesn't expand that on launch.

Answer (score 0):

Since `HTTPPORT` is a variable so it must be defined with a value in *system environment variables* in order to get resolved when called. Check your system variables for `HTTPPORT` and if not found then add new variable with name as `HTTTPPORT` and value `8080`.
Reboot and try again.

Comment: I checked the system environment variables it doesn't contain any HTTPPORT. I will add a new one. And should it be on user variable or system variable?

Comment: @Hazzz define it under system variables